# First element inline-block CSS selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am looking for a CSS selector for the first (or not the first) element in a line.

On the following image, I have 12 blocks separated horizontally by a gray line, this line is not shown on the first element of each line, this is the expected result.

[image]

Is there a way to select the first element of each line using CSS?

Any alternative way to do it with CSS is ok for me, even flex, grid or float.

```css
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div:not(:first-child){
    border-left: 3px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
<div>This is a block</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider a negative margin-left to hide this line:

```css
.wrapper > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 3px solid #999;
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-right: 3px; /*to rectify the removed margin*/
}


/*hide the overflow on the parent element*/
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
  <div>This is a block</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is just a little bit tricky, because you can not target element if you don't know the order. Yet, you could achieve a little trickery with negative margins and `overflow: hidden` property on parent. If that's ok, then you could try this:

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.box {
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 3px solid #999;
  flex: 0 0 70px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
    <div class="box">random bash</div>
  </div>
</div>
```